# Publishing error in Visual Studio 2019 with React with Redux template

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, redux, visual-studio-2019

I am following a React with Redux tutorial using Visual Studio 2019 (with an ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web API) using the standard React with Redux template provided by Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.4.2).

The tutorial says to test out publishing the app which builds it and adds all the published content into the bin/Release folder, but I cannot get it to work due to the import statements inside individual files.

I have not edited any code inside the ClientApp folder in any files except adding some SCSS support and testing it out, and have done the very bare minimum inside my Startup class in the ASP.Net Core code (I just created a basic Middleware component to log httpContext for the response and request stuff so I know this isn't an issue).

The error is shown below:

[image]

```
31/12/19 07:54:14 PM
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__156.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

===================
```

As you can see from the screenshot, it is referring to my imports. For example:

> Cannot find module "../store"

Is referring to the FetchData.tsx file:

```
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
```

The other 2 errors are referring to the WeatherForecasts.ts file:

```
import { Action, Reducer } from "redux";
import { AppThunkAction } from './';
```

This is all template code. I was wondering if it is to do with the relative path but not sure why this would be incorrect as nothing has changed, but the `redux` one is specified inside the package.json file as a dependency just like the other packages so I am unsure why this is not working as well.

Here is my package.json file just in case:

```
{
  "name": "example.web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "connected-react-router": "6.5.2",
    "history": "4.10.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "merge": "1.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-redux": "7.1.1",
    "react-router": "5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "8.1.1",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "svgo": "1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.7.3",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.19",
    "@types/node": "12.11.6",
    "@types/react": "16.9.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.2",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.5",
    "@types/react-router": "5.1.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.0",
    "@types/reactstrap": "8.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.5.0",
    "cross-env": "6.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.6.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/**/*.ts ./src/**/*.tsx"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Sorry that I cannot provide the whole app, but using the standard React with Redux template using Visual Studio 2019 with ASP.Net Core 3.1 should cause the same issue as that is basically all I did to produce the problem. How could I fix this? Thank you.

EDIT:
After deleting package.lock.json and removing node_modules and reinstalling them I got a new error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle example.web@0.1.0~prebuild: example.web@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle example.web@0.1.0~build: example.web@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle example.web@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle example.web@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\<User>\Documents\example\example\example.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\<User>\.dotnet\tools
9 verbose lifecycle example.web@0.1.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\<User>\Documents\example\example\example.Web\ClientApp
10 silly lifecycle example.web@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle example.web@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle example.web@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: example.web@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid example.web@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\<User>\Documents\example\example\example.Web\ClientApp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error example.web@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the example.web@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I tried your code but fail to reproduce. However, I have seen several times that the `node_modules` is broken. I always remove the `node_modules/` folder & `package-lock.json` file completely and make sure there's no errors when running `npm i` manually.

Comment: @itminus thanks. I tried that and I got a new error message but at least it is no longer complaining about modules that should not be missing. Seems like the main problem is `"Failed to exec build script"`

Comment: @itminusI fixed the problem. I had to remove node-sass from package.json and use `npm install node-sass` and `npm rebuild node-sass` as it was added incorrectly. The error message is just very bad and this has been mentioned many times by other people. I also needed to do what you suggested, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. After deleting the package.lock.json and removing the node_modules folder a new error message showed. This error message was more helpful as it was a popular error message on the internet, but at the same time it is incredibly vague:

```
13 verbose stack Error: example.web@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid example.web@0.1.0
```

For me, this was because of the SASS (node-sass module I installed). I read another stackoverflow post that someone else had this problem and it turned out to be 2 lines of CSS. So the error is hard to debug.

My imported SASS files in react were failing to build because I incorrectly installed node-sass.

I fixed it by doing the following steps:

1. `npm install node-sass`
2. `npm rebuild node-sass` - to fix a problem with my node.js version compatibility
3. delete the `package.lock.json` file and node_modules folder
4. `npm install` again